# Asp .Net state server on azure virtual machine

Tags: asp.net, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to get to store my asp .net session on an azure virtual machine. I looked up the virtual's machine Public virtual IP address and I use that address in my web.config.

So in my web.config I have something like this:

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=ip_address:42424" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
<machineKey validationKey="validation_key" decryptionKey="decriptionkey" validation="SHA1" decryption="Auto" />
```

I also changed in the virtual machine's registry to allow remote connection to the state server. 
But still it doesn't work. Could this be a firewall problem? Or azure virtual machine just can't be used for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I misunderstood the way azure virtual machines work. I needed to add an endpoint to the azure virtual machine.

I entered the asp .net state server port in the endpoint in my case it was 42424 and then it worked. I also added rules in the firewall for the asp .net state service.